# User profile image's alt text shows special characters

Tags: media

The user profile image's alt text shows HTML entities instead of quote characters in usernames like *Derek O'Rourke*, for which the alt text is shown as *`Derek O&#039;Rourke's picture`*.

How can I avoid that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Drupal 7, in the template.php of your theme, add this function:

```
function themename_preprocess_user_picture(&$variables) {
  $variables['user_picture'] = htmlspecialchars_decode($variables['user_picture'], ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

The problem arises from the `template_preprocess_user_picture()` function in `user.module.` It passes the alt text through the `t` function, which in turn calls `htmlspecialchars()` and it is here the apostrophe is encoded as `&#039;`

In your theme function, the HTML code of the user picture tag will be available in `$variables['user_picture']`. Passing the HTML code through `htmlspecialchars_decode()` will convert `&#039;` back to an apostrophe.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by 'not working'?. Perhaps some other function is re-encoding the alt text after `themename_preprocess_user_picture()` has decoded it. Try inspecting the `$variables` array in the user picture template, `user-picture.tpl.php` and work back from there.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention Display Suite, but the screenshot you added to your question indicates you are using it. There are so many possible explanations it is difficult to pick just one, but I would suggest disabling DS first and see if it works. Then enable DS again and find out what template is being used (`drush vset theme_debug` might help), then find the corresponding preprocess function and call `htmlspecialchars_decode()` there.

Comment: I disabled the DS and its working fine. And the issue appears when I enable the DS. While going through the "ds"module I found a function function ds_render_user_picture($field) from where alt and titlle text is updated for Display suite.                                                                     
      $alt = t("@user's picture", array('@user' => $name));
    $vars = array('path' => $filepath, 'alt' => $alt, 'title' => $alt);  I have added htmlspecialchars_decode here but no luck.